# TRIÁNGULO ASCII EN PYTHON

Tags: python, vscode, python-3.7, ascii

estoy iniciando y un problema que me han propuesto es realizar este ejercicio en python, solo que mi cabeza no puede dar una solución a la cuestión, me pide imprimir el triángulo pero solo los bordes.
No tengo idea de cómo podría hacerlo, agradezco cualquier ayuda o aclaración.

```
obj1 = input("Ingrese un caracter para rellenar el triángulo: ")
if obj1 != str:
    print("Ingresa un caracter, no un número.")
    obj1 = input("Ingrese un caracter para rellenar el triángulo: ")

h = int(input("Ingrese la altura que desea el triángulo: "))
count = 0
for i in range (1, h+1):
    for j in range (h-i):
        print(" ", end=" ")
        
    for j in range(i):
        print(obj1, end=" ")
        count+=1
    print()

print("El número de", obj1, "es:", count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes abordar el problema pensando en los casos en los que se imprime un borde. Un borde siempre cumple al menos una de estas tres condiciones:

- Es el primer caracter que no sea un " " (espacio) en su fila.
- Es el último caracter en su fila.
- Está en la última fila (borde de abajo / "base" de tu triángulo).

El primer borde es el que va en la primera fila, es el primer caracter de relleno de esa fila y también es el último. En las filas que están entre la primera y la última sólo habrá dos bordes (izquierdo y derecho), esto es, el primero que no sea un caracter " " y el último en cada fila. Por otro lado, la última fila siempre tiene borde, no hay caracteres de espacio.

Así, sin alterar demasiado tu estrategia original, puedes añadir un condicional que imprima el caracter de relleno si al menos una de las condiciones se cumple (por eso van unidas con OR y no con AND). En caso contrario imprimes un espacio para separar los bordes.

En python se usa # para hacer comentarios (afecta toda la línea).

```
for i in range (1, h+1):

    # "Multiplicar" un caracter es crear una cadena
    # solo con ese caracter que tenga la longitud que
    # especificaste despues del *
    # "x" * 5 = "xxxxx"

    offset = " " * (h-i)
    print(offset, end="")
        
    for j in range(i):

        # 0 es la primera posicion
        # range arranca en 0 salvo que especifiques otro valor

        if (j==0 or j==(i-1) or i==h):
            print(obj1, end="")
            # Solo se cuenta cuando se pone bloque
            count+=1
        else: 
            print(" ", end="")
    print()
```

Cabe mencionar que podrías partir de esta base y pensar el dibujo del triángulo en tres secciones: Primera fila (sólo imprimo al final), filas intermedias (imprimo a la izquierda y a la derecha calculando espacios entre esos) y la última fila (imprimo toda la fila). Si te preocupas por cada sección por separado podrás notar que cada una se puede representar con un patrón (o fórmula) y obtener código como el propuesto por @jachguate.

Answer (score 0):

Para dibujar cada línea del triangulo, debes calcular, primero, los espacios que hay desde el inicio de la pantalla hasta el borde del triángulo.

Luego, para dibujar solo el borde, debes imprimir el caracter de este borde y luego calcular los espacios que hay hasta el borde del otro lado, en todas las líneas, excepto en la primera y la última.

En la primera, imprimes solamente el caracter del borde, sin más. Y en la última, debes imprimir toda la línea llena de este caracter, para *cerrar* el triángulo.

En Python, te recomiendo que te acostumbres a utilizar los contadores y rangos iniciando en 0. Probablemente vienes de pascal o de otro lenguaje dónde se acostumbre iniciarlos en 1, pero en Python te va a resultar más natural el uso del 0 y es algo a lo que puedes acostumbrarte sin mucho esfuerzo.

Por otro lado, puedes utilizar el operador `*` con cadenas, para repetirlas una cantidad N de veces, así `" "*7` nos da una cadena de 7 espacios en blanco.

En código, podría lucir más o menos como esto:

```
car = input("Ingrese un caracter para rellenar el triángulo: ")
h = int(input("Ingrese la altura que desea el triángulo: "))

for i in range(h):
    if i==0:
        print(" "*(h-i-1) + car)
    elif i<h-1:
        print(" "*(h-i-1) + car + " "*(i*2-1) + car)
    else:
        print(car*(h*2-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!
Los que te han contestado antes han hecho una excelente labor y no puedo añadir nada.
Te comento un part de cosas del inicio. Cuando escribes:
obj1 = input("Ingrese un caracter para rellenar el triángulo: ")
La variable obj1 se carga por defecto como un string o cadena.
Por otro lado creo que no puedes analizar si una variable es string de esta manera => typeof

Si, segun tu código, el usuario no entra un string y lo vuelve a entrar erróneamente tu código sigue. Cosa que supongo no quieres.
En los casos de revisión de preguntas se acostumbra a sustituir el if por un while o bien un for...if...break
De esta manera, se vuelve a preguntar.

Te pongo el código muy parecido al anterior con un triángulo rectángulo,utilizando strings y que cuenta los caracteres

```
#Piensa cómo harás la entrada de datos, yo te lo dejo sin condiciones.
obj1 = input('Ingrese un caracter para rellenar el triángulo: ')
h = int(input('Ingrese la altura que desea el triángulo: '))
count = 0
for i in range (h-1):
    linea = (h-i-1)*' '+obj1
    count+=1
    if i >0:
        linea += (i-1)*' '+obj1
        count+=1
    print(linea)
print(h*obj1)        
print(f'Número de caracteres = {count+h}')

El resultado te debería salir:
     *
    **
   * *
  *  *
 *   *
******
Número de caracteres = 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada linea consiste en un numero de espacio, luego un asterisco, luego otro numero de espacios y finalmente un asterisco, a excepcion de la primera y la ultima linea, que son casos especiales

Analicemos para n=6:

```
     *     5 espacios, asterisco
    **     4 espacios, asterisco, 0 espacios, asterisco
   * *     3 espacios, asterisco, 1 espacios, asterisco
  *  *     2 espacios, asterisco, 2 espacios, asterisco
 *   *     1 espacios, asterisco, 3 espacios, asterisco
******     6 asteriscos
```

Claramente puedes ver un patron, en este caso la altura del triangulo es n = 6, como la primera y ultima linea son especiales las tratamos a parte.

El primer espacio va desde n-2 hasta 1, el segundo espacio va desde 0 hasta n-3

Hacemos un loop de 4 (eso es n-2) elementos para imprimir estas 4 lineas

```
for i in range(n-2):
```

`i` valdra 0, 1, 2, 3  el primer espacio toma los valores 4,3,2,1 lo que equivale a `4-i`, el segundo espacio toma los valores 0,1,2,3 que es `i`

por lo tanto podemos hacer

```
for i in range(n-2): 
   print(" " * (n-2-i) + "*" + " " * i + "*")
```

Esto nos da:

```
    **
   * *
  *  *
 *   *
```

Hacemos la primera linea, son 5 espacios (n-1) y un asterisco
Y la ultima linea son 6 espacios que es `n`

El codigo completo pues:

```
c = input("Ingrese un caracter para rellenar el triángulo: ")
n = int(input("Ingrese la altura que desea el triángulo: "))

print(" " * (n-1) + c)
for i in range(n-2):
    print(" " * (n-2-i) + c + " " * i + c)
print(c * n)
```